# Using SVG as image replacement for website logo

Tags: html, svg, semantics

With the trend of high resolution displays like retina, people are encouraging the use of icon-fonts or SVG graphics.

My simple question is if I use SVG to replace my website's logo will it have negative affects on SEO? My logo won't be visible in the Google Images etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has been indexing svg files since 2010 [[1]](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html.). The are plenty of logos in svg format visible on google images, try searching for "logo filetype:svg" for example.

Comment: Thanx. Should the .svg be used with the <svg> markup or <img /> ??